# Where do I put SQL commands?

Tags: sql, mysql, datatable

I can't find where I should place my commands to change an existing data table. I am using phpMyAdmin and I am trying to change the name of a column.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you looking for the "ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN old_column_name TO new_column_name;" syntax? Or are you not sure what tool can interact with your database?

Comment: There are a number of MySQL client applications. You can use the MySQL Workbench GUI application, the phpMyAdmin web-based tool, the textual `mysql` client from a terminal window.

Comment: @Error_2646 Thank you for your response! I am not sure what tool or where in my tool to go.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for your comment! I am using phpMyAdmin, but am unsure of how to use it to edit a column.

Comment: Go into the table definition screen, click on the column name and edit it.